# why did this event.url work rather than this one

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cordova

Im using `cordova phonegap 2.5.0`  I had a really hard time getting the `URL` from the new `inAppBrowser`. For some reason only this code workes ---

```
client_browser = window.open(authorize_url, '_blank', 'location=yes');

function iabLoadStop(event) {
    alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
}

client_browser.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
```

The code above works perfect. However the code we will see returns undefined every time! I cant figure out why? can somebody please explain?

```
client_browser.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
```

Comment: Where does your inline function get `event` from?

Comment: The addEventListener call must give the event variable but I'm honestly not too sure besides that. I cant make much sense from the documentation. Javascript is wierd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inline function should accept the parameter `event`

```
client_browser.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
```

Comment: Oh duh! thanks so much, I didnt know a method could give a variable like that.....javascript is wierd.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Docs don't show 'event' as a parameter in the examples